# create function in controller not saving two separate params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tags, parameters

these are the codes

```
<p>
<% form_for @movie do |m| %>
<%= m.label :title, 'Title' %>:
<%= m.text_field :title %></br>
<%= m.label :release_year, 'Release Year' %>:
<%= m.select :release_year, (1900..2011) %></br>
</br>

<% Movie.genres.each do |genre| %>
    <%=h genre %>
    <%= check_box_tag :genre, genre %></br>
<% end%>
</br>

<%= m.submit "Save" %>

<% end %>
</p>
```

and my code in the controller:

```
def create
@movie = Movie.new(params[:movie].merge(:genre))
if @movie.save!
  render show_path
else
  render new_path
end
```

But for whatever reason, I keep getting error messages saying "undefined method `each_pair' for :genre:Symbol" or "cannot find Movie without an ID".  It's not saving properly.

Is it because of my submit form is only the movie form |m| or is it because my create function in the controller is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps instead of

```
params[:movie].merge(:genre)
```

you wanted to do

```
params[:movie].merge(:genre => params[:genre])
```

?

Comment: it's because Hash#merge expects another hash as argument and you are passing a symbol which is essentially string and does not have #each_pair method. when you call method like this: method(:a => b) it is automatically parsed as method({:a => b}) - argument will be hash

Answer (score 0):

Check Firebug in Firefox (or the Chrome developer tools if you're using Chrome, or your app logs if you're using neither), and see what parameters are actually being passed in your scenario? Sounds like your code is expecting to receive a parameter that is not actually being passed. The tools/log should reveal where the breakdown is happening.

Comment: Thanks for answering Normalocity! Your suggestion was actually how I realized where the broken chain was.  But I just didn't know how to repair it.

Comment: So long as you got it figured out. :)